# Example of a sequence $ \{ P_n \} \subseteq [0,1)$ such that $\lambda(\limsup P_n) = 1$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Find an example of a sequence of intervals $ \{ P_n  \}$ such that $ \{ P_n  \} \subseteq [0,1)$, $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\lambda(P_n) = 0$ and yet $\lambda(\limsup P_n) = 1$. In this problem, $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

So what I was going to say is to Let $\mathbb{E} = [0,1) \cap \mathbb{Q}$. I was then going to define $P_n = [q_n, q_n + \frac{1}{n})$ where $q_n \in \mathbb{E}$. Do you think this is the right example? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why not let each $P_n$ be the interval $[0,1)$?

Comment: I forgot to mention that $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \lambda(P_n) = 0$

Answer (score 1):

Your example doesn't work because it may not be true that $q_n+\frac{1}{n}<1$. You could use $[0,q_n]$. Then $\cap_{m=n}^\infty P_n=[0,1)$ for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$. So in particular, $\limsup P_n=[0,1)$

Comment: I forgot to mention that →∞()=0. Would my example still work?

Comment: Your example still fails to satisfy $P_n\subset [0,1)$. I think it could be appropriately modified to work though